# ActiveRecord Limit showing fewer records than exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to show an index of a parent record, with an eager loaded child, order them based off of a child field, and then paginate. This functionality works without adding the `Limit` (or paginate) command, but with it I only receive 3 records of the 50 in my db. Been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what I've done wrong here. I'll start with a simplified Schema, then models, and finally my index controller function.

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140307193043) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "envs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    ...
  end

  add_index "envs", ["name"], name: "index_envs_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "updateresults", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "env_name"
    ...
  end

  add_index "updateresults", ["env_name", "created_at"], name: "index_updateresults_on_env_name_and_created_at", using: :btree

end
```

Env model

```
Class Env < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :updateresults, foreign_key: :env_name, primary_key: :name,
                            dependent: :destroy
    has_one :current_status, -> { order 'created_at DESC' },
                            foreign_key: :env_name, primary_key: :name,
                            class_name: 'Updateresult'
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 20 },
                            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Updateresult model

```
class Updateresult < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :env, foreign_key: :env_name, primary_key: :name
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

Env controller

```
  def index
    @envs = Env.includes(:current_status).order('updateresults.value asc, name asc').paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

SQL for good measure

```
SELECT "envs"."id" AS t0_r0, "envs"."name" AS t0_r1, "envs"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "envs"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "updateresults"."id" AS t1_r0, "updateresults"."content" AS t1_r1, "updateresults"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "updateresults"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "updateresults"."env_name" AS t1_r4, "updateresults"."version" AS t1_r5, "updateresults"."bbj_status" AS t1_r6, "updateresults"."host" AS t1_r7, "updateresults"."repo" AS t1_r8 FROM "envs" LEFT OUTER JOIN "updateresults" ON "updateresults"."env_name" = "envs"."name" ORDER BY updateresults.repo asc, name asc LIMIT 30
```

Also worth mentioning, this test freezes RSpec

```
expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: env.name)
```

Comment: Are you trying to paginate the parent?  It also might not be getting and envs which don't have updateresults

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to paginate the parent. Is that not what I'm doing here? :P In production, all Envs will have at least one updateresult. So I've modeled that in my test system (Though I had thought about that, and need to build something in for this scenario).

Comment: Yes, but I just wanted to be sure.  You definitely don't want limit as that does what you'd expect you can do `.paginate(params[:page]).per(20)` which should get you them in lumps of 20 per page

Comment: Perhaps I worded my title oddly, but paginate ultimately uses a limit command in sql, which is whats causing the problem. Looking at my index function, I think that does pretty close to the same thing (Since the default is 30, right?).

Comment: Shall we move to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50046/activerecord-limit-showing-fewer-records-than-exist)?